# Upgrading .NETv4.7 application to .NET Core v3 and Identity Platform

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-identity-platform

I'm investigating how to convert an Angular+.NETv4.7 application to a .NET Core v3 with Blazor and Identity Platform.

I can log in using Identity Platform and my Azure AD, although I have some advanced questions:
[User stays logged in after deleting from Azure AD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58833240/user-stays-logged-in-after-deleting-from-azure-ad)

I'm now at the part that I want to show the name and the profile photo of the logged-in user. I'm using [this example.](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-1-Call-MSGraph)

It works, I can get the photo and other data but only when I click on the profile link and trigger the Profile controller. The profile data is saved in `ViewData`. But how to get this data in my `_LoginPartial.cshtml`? Should I do the call the Graph in my Home controller as well?

**Update**:
I managed to get it working by creating a `View Component`. Is that the proper workflow? I had to create 4 files to get this working: show the photo and the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Microsoft Identity Platform gave us more trouble than help, we decided to take another route and use Google to authenticate. This made it all much simpler.
I've made a repo with my efforts, feel free to use.
I'll keep enhancing it until I have a sample application that does what I need.

https://bitbucket.org/pmeems/matblazorgooglegsuite/src/develop/